Regex to optionally match groups in any order
Following the pattern from this article, I'm trying to create a regular expression that would capture some groups in arbitrary order.
/(?=.*(?<one>foo))(?=.*(?<two>bar))(?=.*(?<three>baz))/

However, the additional requirement is that the groups must be optional, i.e. it must match all the strings below:
foo bar baz
foo baz bar
baz bar foo
foo bar
foo baz
bar baz
foo
bar
baz

I tried applying a quantifier ? to the capturing group but for some reason it stops capturing that group completely. I'm wondering if that's possible at all?
/(?=.*(?<one>foo)?)(?=.*(?<two>bar)?)(?=.*(?<three>baz)?)/
Here's the demo at Regex101. Would appreciate any advice.

In this case, it make more sense to simply run 3 regex searches. Much simpler to handle and understand. Actually, you may also just use alternation: foo|bar|baz. What is your problem in the first place?

@WiktorStribiżew, unfortunately the alteration won't work because I have to capture named groups. Separate regex searches is my fallback solution, but I would really prefer to have an all-in-one regex for this.

can a group appear multiple times? Ie what about foo bar foo?

@WiktorStribiżew, thanks for taking the time to look into this, but I'm afraid the expression you provided doesn't capture any parts of the testing strings.

I suspect ^(?=.*(?<one>foo))?(?=.*(?<two>bar))?(?=.*(?<three>baz))? could work for you, but it seems it won't work in JavaScript due to how JS regex handles captures in optional groups. I'd re-think the approach anyway.

Yes, I replaced the comment after checking. It won't work in JavaScript. You cannot do what you want in JS regex.

@derpirscher, no I only expect a single appearance of any group matcher. So foo bar foo is not expected.

So it is time to use the backup plan, which is the best anyway.

@vldmr ... The requirement of wanting to target every valid sequence of the many possible variations/combinations is diametral to also having to capture named groups. A short enough and meaningful pattern like ... /^(foo|bar|baz)(?:[ ]+(?!\1)(foo|bar|baz)(?:[ ]+(?!\1|\2)(foo|bar|baz))?)?$/gm ... which accomplishes valid matches has to be based on the alternation of foo|bar|baz together with negative lookaheads which do prevent already captured values from being matched/captured again. Such a solution excludes the usage of named groups.

@vldmr … How does the OP want to handle following single line … "some text… foo foo bar baz foo bar baz foo …and some more text."? Neither the OP's pattern nor any of the provided solutions are capable of validating/matching the following sub-strings … "some text… foo foo bar baz foo bar baz foo  …and some more text." A regex that can achieve such a matching/validation task already does hit the limit of how far one can go with a still readable/maintainable pattern. Only the matches are the values where the OP can start the actual task.

@PeterSeliger, thanks! The actual task looks similar to the example you provided. The goal is to extract some known parameters of a database connector URL where some of them may be lacking, other unknown parameters may be present and order is not guaranteed. The accepted answer does the job even though the pattern (given the amount of params to be extracted) is difficult to read and maintain.

Why does this have opinion-based close votes on it? It's clearly an objectively answerable question.

You can make the entire pattern in each lookahead assertion optional instead of making the keyword optional so that the wildcard wouldn't consume the keyword:
^(?=(?:.*(?<one>foo))?)(?=(?:.*(?<two>bar))?)(?=(?:.*(?<three>baz))?)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Tiw8wu/2

By far the best solution, as it even elegantly balances effort (maintainability/readability) and coverage of the OP's real application criteria.

Why not just use a global flag?


const arr = `foo bar baz
foo baz bar
baz bar foo
foo bar
foo baz
bar baz
foo
bar
baz`.split('\n');

for(const str of arr){
  const result = [...str.matchAll(/(?<one>foo)|(?<two>baz)|(?<three>bar)/g)]
    .reduce((r, m) => (Object.entries(m.groups).forEach(([name, val]) => val && (r[name]=val)), r), {});
  console.log(result);
}



